# factors c() : NA, replacing vs combining

Tags: r

I just stumbled upon a strange conversion aspect of the `c()` function's treatment of factors in R 3.3.1.  Here is a basic example:

```
> x <- factor(c("X", "X", "Y", "Y", "X"))
> x[2] <- NA
> x
[1] X    <NA> Y    Y    X
Levels: X Y
```

all good.  but how do I push an `<NA>` onto x now?  the problem is that the c() function seems to convert factors into integers, so

```
> c(x, NA)
> c(x,NA)
[1]  1 NA  2  2  1 NA
> c(x)
[1] 1 1 2 2 1
```

this seems odd.  logically, the c() function should not convert factors to integers when not necessary.  (curious: is there a good reason?)  is there a c() function for factors?

Comment: The documentation has a lot to say about this (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/c.html). "Note that factors are treated only via their internal integer codes "  this works for factors  `c.factor <- function(..., recursive=TRUE) unlist(list(...), recursive=recursive)`

Comment: `factor(c(levels(x)[x], NA))` and `factor(c(NA, levels(x)[x]))` for both directions of concatenation.

Comment: thanks.  I had looked at my 3.3.1 docs, and this is new docs.  (I should have upgraded sooner!)  but, is there an underlying reason for this behavior by c()?